# Why is the Z very noisy around out of focus objects?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, depth-of-field

I am doing a render of a [tutorial](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-post-apocalyptic-environment) I finished, and when I go compositing it I get a weird jitter on a defocused object. The tutorial had this too (at 1:04:00), but I wonder if it is possible to remove it. I tried adding a blur/defocus node but it ended messing up with the map value.

This is the jitter I'm talking about:

[image: Node setup]

And this is my node setup:

[image: Node setup]

Comment: Just raise your samples.

Comment: I think they were at 24 when rendering. The rest of the scene looks fine, it's jittered only when I try to apply the map value.

Comment: Try raising them and see what happens...

Comment: Also, are you using render DOF?

Comment: Are you using cycles or BI? Could you link to the tutorial in question?

Comment: try increasing your F-Stop value

Comment: I've made an [imgur album](http://imgur.com/a/zDaI1) with some attempts. I'm using a simple scene to make rendering faster. @GiantCowFilms yes, I tried both the number distance and the object focus, both have the same problem. And raising the samples didn't worked, as you can see in the album.

Comment: @gandalf3 I'm using cycles, but even in BI the edges are a bit jittered without defocus (couldn't get defocus to work). [Tutorial Link](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-post-apocalyptic-environment) You can see the jitter at about 1:04:00. It isn't much noticeable in his final render because he made the fog a bit darker.

Comment: @G.Rassovsky I tried at max f/stop, it improved things a bit but the edges were still a bit jittered. But at max f/stop I'd lose the defocus. By the way, thanks for trying to help guys.

Comment: Usually it's a matter of balancing the F-stop and shutter speed, in a camera, in order to get the right picture. I am not sure what that equivalent would be but I would suggest playing with the distance of focus too, along with the F-stop. (putting it to max is way too much, it should be more subtle than that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the Z always gets only one sample, so it's always noisy around defocused objects regardless of the number of scene samples. However using the mist pass (which was added since that tutorial was made) instead of the Z gives a better result:

[image]

To define the distance/thickness of the mist, enable the mist display in the camera settings so that you can see a visualization in the 3D view:

[image]

Then adjust the start and depth of the mist in world settings:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot!