# Is Z-Render Pass accuracy dependent on sample count? Are others like object id? (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-passes

So I have a single-frame project and want to send it to a renderfarm that does not support OpenEXR or compositing (SheepIt). 
Can I simply do a 1 sample pass on my computer and still get high accuracy compositing passes like Z-Buffer, Object ID and so on, to combine them later with the renderfarm result?

Comment: Yes, actually those passes only use 1 sample already. However some passes similar to those (such as mist) *do* use all the samples. Depending on the exact nature of your scene you may be able to get away with lower samples for mist (I would still use more like 50 or so), but in some cases (e.g. with motion blur or DoF, where multiple objects are visible in the same pixel) more may be needed.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14925/599 and (somewhat) http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7025/599

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, *Z pass*, *ObjectID* and alike are not dependent on Cycles render samples. Their visual output will always be the same like rendered with 1 sample - so not nice.

It's better to obtain them in Cycles with a different method - *Z pass* with *Mist pass* or *Ray-depth shaders*, *ID-masks* with random-colored shadeless materials for example.

Or get them from Blender Internal (you want to use *Full Sample* there).

Here is a little table what is (green) and is not (red) dependent on render samples:

[image]

Comment: Why and to which point are Emission, Environment, Mist, Normal and UV passes dependent of the samples amount? I always thought samples didn't change anything except anti-aliasing.

Comment: @piegames Why: because of the nature of unbiased rendering. More samples equal less noise for the pass. For each AA sample (in branched pathtracing) you can set the amount of emission samples, volume (mist) samples, AO, direct/indirect and so on.

Comment: The Mist pass is not a Volume pass. And what about Normal/UV and Environment pass?

Comment: Why is normal dependent on # samples??? I thought it is purely geometric, just like depth? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @SibbsGambling you need samples to clear alias on object edges. Without it the pass would be useless as the index and depth passes are.