# White pixels around objects rendered with 2D Background

Tags: transparency

I'm new to Blender and have been trying to render objects against a 2D background using a shadow catching method posted by Andrew Price. Here's a link to the screenshot of the node structure ([Node Setup](http://panosphere.ca/images/Test/NodeSetup.png)).

[image]

It's a low quality demo but clearly shows white pixels where the object edges meet the background. Here is a link to the result ([Test Result](http://panosphere.ca/images/Test/ShadowCatcherResult01.png)).

[image]

Does anyone have a fix? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know it may seem counter-intuitive to uncheck anti-aliasing, but that might be introducing the edge.

Comment: You should do this like this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19767/7777. Having passes with transparency eliminates the edges introduced with ID masks. ID masks are limited, see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36089/7777