# A good way to render objects on a photo background that works also with focus-blurred margins

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-passes, blur

I'm trying to render with Cycles on a photo background using [Blender Guru's](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/render-onto-photo-background) compositor nodes:

[image]

[ Here, the foreground objects are obId=1 and are on layer 1 (rendered in RenderLayer); reconstructed background objects are obId=2 and are on both layer 1 and 2. Layer 2 is rendered as "ground". ]

However, in the current frame the main subject is supposed to be out of focus. As a result, both the ObIndex=1 pass (foreground) and the ObIndex=2 pass (reconstructed background objects, *i.e.* shadow catchers) are blurry. See the first two panels below:

[image]

As you can see, the blurriness doesn't consist in a smooth ramp of fractional intensities; it is instead a random cloud of blacks and whites, which will give an unusable result in terms of foreground/background separation (see the third panel).

I guess this is because the ObIndex pass only contains one *integer* per pixel, that can be either one of the "Pass Index" values assigned to the objects in the scene, but not anything in between.

So, my question: **is there a better way to blend a rendered foreground onto a photo background that works well with blurred objects**?

---

Here's a blend file with the scene described above.

[image]

Comment: Its a known limitation of the current ID mask system sadly. I suggest that you might need to separate by layer instead of object?

Comment: @3pointedit my objects are separated both by layer and by obId. I'd like some help in figuring out a way to not use obId at all or to use it in combination to something else (*e.g.* rendering against a transparent background). I can try myself as I'm familiar with image processing, but I'm not really fluent in all the render layers settings so I'd better check if anyone has a better approach than I would have.

Comment: Why do you need the ID mask cutout? Why not just alpha over your layer on the background? I guess you'll need a shadow catcher.

Comment: @3pointedit thanks for the suggestion. However, as I mentioned, I'd be happy to see how a working solution could be implemented in the render settings and compositor nodes. If you can suggest such setup, please provide an answer and I'll try it out

Comment: All I've tried was oversample, that is render at a higher resolution then scale down to required dimensions. But the image remained coarse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As 3dpointedit pointed out, there is a limitation of the current ID mask system:

[Is Z-Render Pass accuracy dependent on sample count? Are others like object id? (Cycles)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36072/is-z-render-pass-accuracy-dependent-on-sample-count-are-others-like-object-id/36089#36089)

As such, these layers are unusable for any post-processing workflow. You need to obtain these layers differently, or build the pipeline in another way.

The correct way of compositing onto a background is detailed here:

[Cycles: Shadeless "Shadow-catcher" Material for Rendering onto Footage](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19765/cycles-shadeless-shadow-catcher-material-for-rendering-onto-footage/19767#19767)

In short, you need to put your objects in layer 1, your shadow catchers in layer 2, and the lights in both layers. The render layers will be "object only" (include: 1), "shadows" (include: 2), and "clean background" (include: 2, exclude: 1). Render with transparent background.

This will give you these layers:

- "shadows"

  [image]
- "clean background"

  [image]

Dividing the former with the latter you get the shadow:

[image]

You multiply this shadow with your backdrop, and you alpha-over the object into your backdrop. You have to render the scene 3 times though.

You can also use the new Shadow catcher feature of Blender 2.79, but it will only produce black shadows.

Comment: Yea, it works *almost* perfectly. I whish I had found your render layout earlier! Unfortunately there is a very thin line https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRsAN.png at the border of my shadow catcher, that is more evident the more out of focus the object is (I can fix that by designing a shadow catcher that extends to the boundaries of the frame, but it'd be expensive computationally)

Comment: Never mind, easily fixed by disabling the Alpha information from the Divide node

Comment: I can see only one problem now: this composite setup, unlike the one in my question, doesn't account for objects in the reconstructed "ground" to occlude rendered objects. Is it possible to revert this ability with just 3 render layers or one has to know in advance what will be in front of what?

Comment: @NicolaSap If you need to occlude your first render layer (objects) with something, you can use the Mask layer option. Simply include your second scene layer as a mask layer for your first render layer. You can also create a special extra scene layer with geometry just for masking purposes.

Answer (score 1):

**I've found a workaround** but real solutions are still very much appreciated!

This workaround is far from being optimal, as it depends on several parameters, it works only at Render Size = 100% (I'm not sure why the Gaussian Blur at smaller sizes creates light artifacts), it blurs the background as well as the subject, and it blurs by 1-2 pixels also borders that are supposed to be sharp.

---

### Blurring the noise out

[image]

This is obtained by blurring in post-production the area where the ObIndex mask is patterned, that can be detected by blurring it and finding non-integer regions.

[image]

1. The yellow box is the same as in my question, taken from a Blender Guru tutorial.
2. The red box is a Gaussian blur of the final composite.
3. The Gaussian blurred image and the image itself are mixed using a Mix node with a *Fac* created in the green box. The latter is obtained by manipulating the ObIndex=1 ID mask. Zoom:

   [image]

   This is what the result of the green node looks like:

   [image]