# Is there any way not to render the combined pass and only output the passes I need?

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-passes

[image]

I want to output multiple passes using the File Output node in the compositor.

However, Blender's default output directory works together and outputs a combined pass.

When I type no directory in the input box, an image is created in the folder where Blender is installed.

I feel it like a waste of CPU because I want to get only another passes.

Is it necessary to output the combined pass in Blender?

Or is there any way to only output the passes I need in the compositor?

Comment: AFAIK you can't omit combined pass rendering. But if you use plain shaders and no lights in the scene this will hardly impact your render time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102297/render-passes-separately